# Manhwa where a woman is reincarnated as the daughter of an emperor and introduces cultivation magic to the realm

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation, cultivation

I read this manhwa ages ago and stopped reading because I lost interest but now I wanna start reading it again but I can’t remember what it’s called.

It starts with a girl from the cultivation world and I think she gets betrayed by a guy before being reincarnated (can’t really remember). She then gets reincarnated into a fantasy world as a baby. She has a twin brother and is the daughter of the emperor. She’s also seen as less important for being a daughter and gets neglected for a bit until later on in the story her dad and brother grow to like her and basically everyone loves her and she introduces cultivation as a type of magic and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely *[How to be a Princess](https://kitsu.io/manga/how-to-be-a-princess)*, aka *A Queen's Law of Survival*.

> She used to be an immortal. **She gave up her immortality for eternal love, yet was betrayed by the one she loved**. In a twist of fate, she was reborn as a queen in another world. Now, she is faced with the ever-impending danger of being sacrificed by her cold-blooded father to her brother. Can she find a way to rewrite her destiny...?

The protagonist is originally a cultivator, but gives up immortality for love. She is betrayed by her love and killed, but reincarnates as a baby.

[image: Past life]

She reincarnates as a princess, but in a patriarchal society, so she isn't considered for inheritance. Her father has many other daughters, but only one son, and he has been cursed. The protagonist was intended to be a sacrifice to save her brother, but this isn't done immediately due to her unlucky appearance.

[image]

I assume she practices cultivation again after reincarnating, but I didn't read enough to confirm this.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Twin/s` and `Cultivation`

Comment: I think this was initially licensed and officially translated into English, but it's listed as removed. I don't know if another company (legally) hosts the official translations or not.